# What's the correct sentence to use in this situation?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

My native language lacks tenses. I'll try to express tenses using headlines and please, tell me what's the correct tense to use. I would appreciate it if you corrected my words if they sound unnatural.

**In the past,**

When a customer calls us to order something, we tell him: "That'll be $5". Sometimes, we say: "Including fees (or fees are included)".

**Now,**

We tell him: "That'll be $5 including delivery and processing fees".

A customer may tell me that he never paid processing fees or delivery fees.

Here's my reply that might have inaccurate tenses:

> Fees were applied but we didn't tell our customers about them for the
>   sake of simplicity (or to make things easier) but now, we would like to give you our customers more details (or detailed explanation) about fees.

Thank you so much,

Comment: really in your native language you would say the same for 'i went for a run', 'I am running' and 'I will go for a run'?

Comment: @WendyG  Yes, some languages just use a time frame:  *"I go for a run yesterday"* makes perfect sense, especially in context.

Comment: @Andrew thanks, spot who has only ever spoke Latin languages

Comment: @WendyG [some more info](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-languages-that-don%C2%B4t-use-verb-tenses-to-express-the-concept-of-time-and-if-so-how-do-they-express-the-idea-of-time-past-present-and-future).   :)

Comment: @WendyG Yes, In Arabic, there are no perfect continuous tenses. No past perfect. Present continuous is rarely used I think. Sometimes, we use sentences without any verbs such as "I student" and that's why I always forget verb "To be" in English.

Comment: @WendyG But of course, we have past and present. Here's your 3 sentences in my language: "I went for a run", "I run = I'm running", "I'll go for a run = I'm gonna run".

Comment: @user2824371  Your sentence is fine as written.  I'm not sure what else to add to an answer unless you can give more detail where you find tenses confusing?  Also, as a suggestion, you can say you offer customers an *itemized receipt* (which includes the detail of the fees and other charges).

Comment: @Andrew Is it also okay to say: ...we were not telling... or ...we haven't been telling... Is it polite enough so that I can say it to customers?

Comment: @user2824371  yes, it's polite, although it may not be diplomatic to tell customers that in the past you've been *withholding information* from them.  For a few dollars it doesn't matter, but if the contract was for thousands of dollars, with hidden fees, it could be a problem.  Instead as I suggested you tell them you're now offering an *itemized* bill or a *breakdown* of costs, so they know exactly what they're paying.

Comment: @WendyG I can confirm that too. I'm from Thailand and we don't use any tenses here in our language. We simply specify the time.

Comment: @user2824371  Please see my edited answer.  I added more detail.

Comment: @WendyG - Of course, the funny thing is that English technically doesn't have a future tense either.  Today I *run*, yesterday I *ran*, tomorrow I... *will run* ?  That's actually not so much an inflected future tense as it is a modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence is fine and polite as written.  I have no grammatical suggestions.

However there may be more *diplomatic* ways to tell customers that you have included extra charges in the past, but not actually told them about it.  This depends entirely on the context.

The general term is *charge* for costs associated with an item or service.  You can *charge* a customer for the item itself or the service itself, and also charge them additional costs associated with other related expenses.

If you are a company that *sends* products to people through the mail, then *shipping* (the cost to send the product) is an expected cost.  Sometimes this is referred to as *shipping and handling*, abbreviated as *S&H*.  It's not uncommon to state the total price for an item, *including shipping and handling*.

A *fee* is usually the cost associated with a *service* of some kind, for example a *registration fee*, a *processing fee*, a *licensing fee*, and so on.  Fees may also be *penalties* for some situation, such as a *late fee* or a *returned check fee*. There may be fees associated with the cost of delivering a product, if the delivery requires some kind of special service (an *installation fee*, for example).

A general way to talk about a document that details the charges in the bill is an *itemized* bill, or more formally a *bill of sale*. Less formally you can talk about an *itemized receipt*, or a *breakdown of costs*.

So, again as a suggestion:

> In the past we **included shipping** in the total cost of the item, but we have decided to provide an **itemized receipt** to our customers so they can see a **detailed breakdown** of the **charges**.